# ipywidgets: button.on_click() has output delay

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

## Introduction

I am trying to make a small tool for classifying images using the ipywidgets in a Jupyter Notebook, but I  am having some trouble aligning the classes and the images. Do you have any suggestion how to fix this.

## What I did

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import glob

# My images
image_paths = glob.glob("./images/*.png")

# Display image
def display_image(path):    
    file = open(path, "rb")
    image = file.read()
    return widgets.Image(
                value=image,
                format='png',
                width=700,
                height=700,
            )

# Dropdown
def create_dropdown():
    return widgets.Dropdown(
        options=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"],
        value='5',
        description='Category:',
        disabled=False
    )

# Creating widgets
input_dropdown = create_dropdown()
button = widgets.Button(description="Submit")
output_image = widgets.Image()
output_image.value = display_image(image_paths[-1]).value

# Define function to bind value of the input to the output variable 
def bind_input_to_output(sender):
    image_path = image_paths[-1]
    image_score = input_dropdown.value
    next_image_path = image_paths.pop()
    print(image_score, image_path)
    output_image.value = display_image(next_image_path).value
    
# Tell the text input widget to call bind_input_to_output() on submit
button.on_click(bind_input_to_output)

# Displaying widgets
display(output_image, input_dropdown, button)
```

## Results

With the above code I end up categorising the upcoming picture, but I really don't understand why. It seems the widgets does not update the image the first time I press the button.

Comment: Hard to test this without the input file of pngs, can you share?

Comment: It was just a bunch of random images, but I will update post to include downloading some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def bind_input_to_output(sender):
    image_path = image_paths.pop()
    image_score = input_dropdown.value
    next_image_path = image_paths[-1]
    print(image_score, image_path)
    output_image.value = display_image(next_image_path).value
```

pop first and give next filename at last item